# JS Functions work in Chrome & IE, but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm no expert in Javascript or any of the sort, so here goes.
I'm trying to get these functions to work with Firefox.
They work in Chrome and in IE with no issues. Its in Firefox that it indicate its not defined.

**Functions**:

```
    function fnScrollandBlink(element) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fnScrollSmooth(element, null);
    fnBlink(element);
}

function fnBlink(element) {
    var blinkAmount = 2
        //event.preventDefault();
        //Multiple elements must be seperated by ; simbol.
        //this will seperate it in to an array.
    var arrayElementsBlink = element.split(";");
    var oldBlinkElementsToStop;
    //Stoping all blinks
    $.each(oldBlinkElementsToStop, function(index, blinkToStop) {
        $('#' + blinkToStop).finish();
        $('#' + blinkToStop).fadeIn(0);
    });
    //Start blinking the clicked option
    $.each(arrayElementsBlink, function(index, elementToBlink) {
        var blinkCurrAmo = 1;
        while (blinkCurrAmo <= blinkAmount) {
            $('#' + elementToBlink).fadeOut('fast');
            $('#' + elementToBlink).fadeIn('fast');
            blinkCurrAmo++;
        }
    });
    oldBlinkElementsToStop = arrayElementsBlink;
}

function fnScrollSmooth(element, offsetTop) {
    //event.preventDefault();
    //Multiple elements must be seperated by ; simbol.
    //this will seperate it in to an array.
    var scrollToID = element.split(";");
    var offsetTop, offsetTopDefault;
    offsetTopDefault = 200;
    if (offsetTop == null) {
        offsetTop = offsetTopDefault;
    }
    //Move to section before blinking
    $('html, body').stop(); //Stop current animation
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + scrollToID[0]).offset().top - offsetTop
    }, 500);
}
```

Im calling the function ***fnScrollandBlink*** in the html code using:

```
onClick="fnScrollandBlink('elementID');"
```

This, what it should do is scroll to that section in the webpage and blink the element 2 times.

As i said, it works for IE and Chrome.

You can see an example of the code here:[codepen test code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bWxbrO)

Or you can use the stackoverflow version below:

```js
function fnScrollandBlink(element) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fnScrollSmooth(element, null);
  fnBlink(element);
}

function fnBlink(element) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //Multiple elements must be seperated by ; simbol.
  //this function will seperate it in to arrays.
  var blinkAmount = 2
  var arrayElementsBlink = element.split(";");
  var oldBlinkElementsToStop;
  //Stoping all blinks
  $.each(oldBlinkElementsToStop, function(index, blinkToStop) {
    $('#' + blinkToStop).finish();
    $('#' + blinkToStop).fadeIn(0);
  });

  //Start blinking the clicked option
  $.each(arrayElementsBlink, function(index, elementToBlink) {
    var blinkCurrAmo = 1;
    while (blinkCurrAmo <= blinkAmount) {
      $('#' + elementToBlink).fadeOut('fast');
      $('#' + elementToBlink).fadeIn('fast');
      blinkCurrAmo++;
    }
  });
  oldBlinkElementsToStop = arrayElementsBlink;
}

function fnScrollSmooth(element, offsetTop) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var scrollToID = element.split(";");
  var offsetTop, offsetTopDefault;
  offsetTopDefault = 200;
  if (offsetTop == null) {
    offsetTop = offsetTopDefault;
  }
  //Move to section before blinking
  $('html, body').stop(); //Stop current animation
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + scrollToID[0]).offset().top - offsetTop
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <b>Title 1</b>:
    <br> TEST TEXT
    <br> Click here and it should <a href="#" onClick="fnScrollandBlink('testJump');">Scroll and blink after</a>.
    <br> TEST TEXT
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<ul>
  <li id="testJump">
    <b>Title 2</b>:
    <br> Test text test text test text test text test text
    <br> Test text test text test text test text test text
    <br> Test text test text test text test text test text
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br> End Test
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Any errors in your console for FF? What exactly is not defined?

Comment: Depending on how the functions are loaded.
If its loaded from a seperate file, it shows: 
`ReferenceError: fnScrollandBlink is not defined`
If its loaded from inside the html file (<script>code</script>), it shows:
`ReferenceError: event is not defined`

Comment: Seems like it was my mistake for the functions to not work.
I was using a local file on a PC and its JS.
The reason why functions wasn't loading in FF is that it wasn't loading de JS at all, but i didn't understand why, until now.

The problem is that Firefox doesn't read normal explorer DIR. I had to translate the DIR to normal html syntax URL with `%20` and the bunch, for example: `file:///c:/blink%20folder/blink.js`

Comment: What I still don’t get is why the `event.preventDefault();` doesn't work in FF, but in Chrome and IE it works. FF indicates `ReferenceError: event is not defined` but Chome and IE work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to all.
To start, I said it works as is with Chrome and IE. Both the function declaration as is using DIR address in the `<head>` section and the `event` that's not declared but works never the less. It’s just in FF (firefox), both don’t work.

**The solution to both problems, (for me at least):**

I was using a local file on a PC and its JS. The reason why functions wasn't loading in FF is that it wasn't loading de JS at all, but i didn't understand why, until now. The problem is that Firefox doesn't read normal explorer DIR. I had to translate the DIR to normal html syntax URL with `%20` and the bunch, for example: `file:///c:/blink%20folder/blink.js`

Second problem was the event not working in FF, well I tried multiple options but the on that worked was declaring the event in the actual calling. The only problem is that I have to declare the event in every function for that case, but I don’t really care.

So calling with onClick would look like this, adding the event:

```
onClick="fnScrollandBlink(event,'IntEmAdd;testtop');"
```

The primary function called would look like this, with the event in place:

```
function fnScrollandBlink (event, element){
    event.preventDefault();
    fnScrollSmooth(event, element,null);
    fnBlink(event, element);
}
```

Example snippet live:

```js
function fnScrollandBlink(event, element) {
  event.preventDefault();
  fnScrollSmooth(event, element, null);
  fnBlink(event, element);
}

function fnBlink(event, element) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //Multiple elements must be seperated by ; simbol.
  //this function will seperate it in to arrays.
  var blinkAmount = 2
  var arrayElementsBlink = element.split(";");
  var oldBlinkElementsToStop;
  //Stoping all blinks
  $.each(oldBlinkElementsToStop, function(index, blinkToStop) {
    $('#' + blinkToStop).finish();
    $('#' + blinkToStop).fadeIn(0);
  });

  //Start blinking the clicked option
  $.each(arrayElementsBlink, function(index, elementToBlink) {
    var blinkCurrAmo = 1;
    while (blinkCurrAmo <= blinkAmount) {
      $('#' + elementToBlink).fadeOut('fast');
      $('#' + elementToBlink).fadeIn('fast');
      blinkCurrAmo++;
    }
  });
  oldBlinkElementsToStop = arrayElementsBlink;
}

function fnScrollSmooth(event, element, offsetTop) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var scrollToID = element.split(";");
  var offsetTop, offsetTopDefault;
  offsetTopDefault = 200;
  if (offsetTop == null) {
    offsetTop = offsetTopDefault;
  }
  //Move to section before blinking
  $('html, body').stop(); //Stop current animation
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#' + scrollToID[0]).offset().top - offsetTop
  }, 500);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <b>Title 1</b>:
    <br> TEST TEXT
    <br> Click here and it should <a href="#" onClick="fnScrollandBlink(event, 'testJump');">Scroll and blink after</a>.
    <br> TEST TEXT
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<ul>
  <li id="testJump">
    <b>Title 2</b>:
    <br> Test text test text test text test text test text
    <br> Test text test text test text test text test text
    <br> Test text test text test text test text test text
  </li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br> End Test
```

Comment: Unless someone has a better way for the event issue in FF, I’ll use this method.